# Model Collection not refreshed after attach or detach (many to many) in Laravel Livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I've problem on refreshing model collection after detach on Laravel livewire. I want to remove detached item from view without refresh full page, but it seem not work. it need to refresh full page to re render the view. I have tried to `$model->refresh()`  after `detach()`, and its work but  `$model->refresh()` duplicate already loaded relationship query.
Here the route:

```
Route::get('/order/{order}', function (Order $order) {
    $order = $order->load(['worklist.khs:id,mou_id,worklist_id,khs', 'worklist.category:id,category', 'materials']);
    return view('livewire.order.index-order',  ['order' => $order]);
})->name('view.order');
```

Livewire Component:

```
class ViewOrder extends Component
{
    public Order $order;
    public function delete($id)
    {
        $work = Worklist::find($id);
        $this->order->worklist()->detach($work);
        $this->order->refresh();  //refreshed, but relationship query duplicated
        $this->tempTotal();
    }

public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.order.view-order', ['worklist' => $this->order->worklist]);
    }
{
```

Screenshoot of duplicated query if use `$model->refresh()`:
[image: duplicated]

is there any workaround to refresh relationship collection without full page refresh or refresh with `$model->refresh()` without duplication of query?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are hard-refreshing the whole order object, inclusing all it's eagerloaded relations. When you just refresh the worklist you can save a query.

```php
    public function delete($id)
    {
        $work = Worklist::find($id);
        $this->order->worklist()->detach($work);
        $this->order->worklist()->refresh();
        $this->tempTotal();
    }
```